# "Complex" ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, rails-activerecord

having some trouble setting up some Active Record relationships.

`Users` 
`Leagues`

`Users` have many `PrimaryLeagues`
`Users` have many `SecondaryLeagues`

I would like to be able to write `@user.primary_leagues` and get a list of `Leagues`  that have been set as primary. and `@user.secondary_leagues` and get a list of `Leagues` that have been set as secondary.

Currently here is how my classes are set up, but it is wrong somehow....

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :primary_leagues, class_name: 'PrimaryLeague', foreign_key: 'league_id'

has_many :secondary_leagues, class_name: 'SecondaryLeague', foreign_key: 'league_id'
```

...

```
class PrimaryLeague < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :league
```

...

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :primary_users, class_name: 'PrimaryLeague', foreign_key: 'user_id'
has_many :secondary_users, class_name: 'SecondaryLeague', foreign_key: 'user_id'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you want to use only two classes for the whole thing (and that makes sense). So:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many        :primary_league_ownerships
  has_many        :primary_leagues,
                  :through => :primary_league_ownerships,
                  :source => :league
  has_many        :secondary_league_ownerships
  has_many        :secondary_leagues,
                  :through => :secondary_league_ownerships,
                  :source => :league
end

class PrimaryLeagueOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to      :user
  belongs_to      :league
end

class SecondaryLeagueOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to      :user
  belongs_to      :league
end

class League < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many        :primary_league_ownerships
  has_many        :primary_users,
                  :through => :primary_league_ownerships,
                  :source => :user
  has_many        :secondary_league_ownerships
  has_many        :secondary_users,
                  :through => :secondary_league_ownerships,
                  :source => :user
end
```

Keep in mind that `:class_name` is supposed to be the actual class that will hold the target association.

Comment: depa thanks! Leagues can have many primary_users ... I would also like to be able to say @league.primary_users ... thought maybe I need a has many through association?

Comment: assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: association_foreign_key (ArgumentError) .... should it be a has_and_belongs_to_many association?

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake. It probably should have been `:foreign_key` rather than `:association_foreign_key`. If you look at the options accepted by a `has_many` association, `:association_foreign_key` simply isn't one of them. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many

Comment: Thanks depa. I figured that and updated in my code. Might want to update answer in case others see. Great help... running my tests now ... seeing if this all works!

Comment: Could not find the source association(s) :primary_league or :primary_leagues in model PrimaryLeagueOwnership. Try 'has_many :primary_leagues, :through => :primary_league_ownerships, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :user or :league?

Comment: Got that error when I asked for current_user.primary_leagues in my controller

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37461/discussion-between-depa-and-slindsey3000)